# Bot XCTests fail with OSStatus error -1712 AppleEvent timed out

Tags: ios, xcode, bots, xcode-server

I have a bot running, and all of my XCTests fail with (OSStatus error -1712). The logs are not very helpful but I think it fails after this line:

`Launch session started, setting a disallow-finish-token on the run operation.`

I have googled that, but others don't seem to have the -1712 error code.

The test cases all complete on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I hate this type of answer, but the solution was to upgrade to El Capitan. After calling Apple, they thought it was a bug with Xcode 7.0.1, and Server running on Yosemite. After the upgrade, it has worked perfectly.